# Como puedo agregar una opcion manualmente al combobox para posteriormente utilizarlo

Tags: javascript, php, combobox

Estoy trabajando con PHP y tengo varios combobox lo que necesito es que dentro del mismo combobox, me aparezca una opcipon de "agregar nuevo elemento". Por ejemplo:

Combobox: Tipo de falla

1. Motor
2. Electrica
3. Mecanica
4. Agregar nuevo elemento

Y ya sea bien que la opción de agregar nuevo elemento sea editable o que me permita en otra ventana agregar esa opción a la base de datos para posteriormente poder seleccionarla.

Asì tengo el código

```js
$(document).ready(function() {       
  $('#tipofalla').multiselect({    
    nonSelectedText: 'Tipo Falla',
    enableFiltering: true,  
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    buttonWidth: 350,
    maxHeight: 300        
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="tipofalla" name="tipofalla[]" class="form-control">
    echo <option value="" selected disabled>Tipo de Falla</option>
    <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tipofalla ORDER BY id ASC";
      $statement = $koneksi->prepare($query);
      $statement->execute();
      $result = $statement->fetchAll();
      foreach ($result as $row)
        {
          echo '<option value="' . $row["description"] . '">' . $row["description"] . '</option>';
        }
    ?> 
    <option value="Motor">Motor</option>
    <option value="Mecanica">Mecanica</option>
    <option value="Añadir">Añadir tipo de falla</option>
  </select>
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer esto

Comment: Hay un `echo`  fuera de las etiquetas de php... ;)

Comment: Puedes escuchar los cambios del `select` y cuando sea elegida la opción "Agregar nuevo..."  lanzar el código que pide el valor del elemento nuevo y agregarlo. Revisa [este tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-add-remove-options/) para más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir un listener en el select y que se active solamente cuando alguien seleccione la opción "Añadir tipo de falla".

Te dejo un ejemplo básico que te permitirá abrir una nueva pestaña en el navegador al seleccionar "Añadir tipo de falla" y en esa nueva página puedes hacer un sistema para añadir fallas nuevas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {       
var dropdown = document.getElementById("tipofalla");

dropdown.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if(dropdown.value == "Añadir")
    {
        window.open("INTRODUCE LA URL DONDE QUIERES REDIRIGIR PARA AÑADIR NUEVA CATEGORÍA AQUÍ", '_blank').focus();
    }
});

});
```

Comment: muy bien, le buscare por ese lado